# How to update the score for every radioButton of the radioGroup/position the selected?

Tags: java, android, radio-group

I have a Quiz app [sourcecode](https://github.com/axelmukwena/celebrityQuiz) with multiple radioGroups in a recyclerView and I want everytime a correct radioButton in a certain position (radioGroup) is selected, it should update a score `correct++` and send it to an activity as below.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            if (checked) {
                int radioButtonID = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = mRadioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int selectedAnswerIndex = mRadioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                RadioButton r = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(selectedAnswerIndex);
                String  selectedAnswer = r.getText().toString();

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Object object = mArrayList.get(position);
                String correctAnswer = ((Quiz) object).mCorrectAnswer;

                if (selectedAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
                    correct++;
                    editor.putInt("score", correct);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        }
```

This works but only on one radioGroup, as in if I select another radioButton from a different position, the score `correct` is always 1 probably because it is reset to default before `onClick` funtion is executed again.

My possible solution would be a loop `i <= arrayList.size()` to contain `if (checked)` to prevent score `correct` from being reset to default = 0, but I don't know where to place it and what to contain, because it's not mandatory for the user to select from each radioGroup (unless for the simplest scenario it's a requirement).

How can I update the score for every radioButton of the radioGroup/position the selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the for loop solved everything

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) {
                if (checked) {
                    int radioButtonID = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    View radioButton = mRadioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                    int selectedAnswerIndex = mRadioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                    RadioButton r = (RadioButton) mRadioGroup.getChildAt(selectedAnswerIndex);
                    String selectedAnswer = r.getText().toString();

                    Object object = mArrayList.get(position);
                    String correctAnswer = ((Quiz) object).mCorrectAnswer;

                    if (selectedAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
                        correct++;
                        editor.putInt("score", correct);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```